# Find a function $f$ which is $L^p$ integrable but not $L^\infty$ integrable satisfies $\int_{supp(f)} e^{|f|} dx =1$

Tags: real-analysis

Find a function $f$ which is $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ integrable but not $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies $\int_{supp(f)} e^{|f|} dx =1$.

I have no idea how to find such function belongs to $L^p\cap  (L^\infty)^c$.

If $m(supp(f))<\infty, \frac{1}{m(supp(f))}=\int_{supp(f)}e^{|f|}\frac{1}{m(supp(f))}\geq e^{\int_{supp(f)}\frac{|f|}{m(supp(f))}}\geq 1$, so $m(supp(f))<1$.

Comment: Try a function like $f(x) = \log 2^n = n\log 2$ whenever $x\in [n, n+\frac{1}{4^n}]$, you might need to add/change constants.

Comment: The "standard" examples of functions which are $L^p$ and not $L^\infty$ are $x^{1/(1+\varepsilon)p}$ on $[0,1]$. These are also useful as examples of functions that are $L^p$ but not $L^r$ for $r \geq (1+\varepsilon)p$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $x^{-1/((1+\varepsilon)p)}$. Being concrete, $f(x)=x^{-1/2}$ is $L^1$ but not $L^\infty$, nor is it $L^p$ for $p \geq 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I will finish what I stated in the comment, I wrote that down in a rush.
Define
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \log 2^n \chi_{[n, n+\frac{1}{4^n}]}$$
We see that
$$\int_{supp(f)} e^{|f|} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n \cdot \frac{1}{4^n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} =1.$$
Clearly $f\not\in L^\infty$, to see $f\in L^p$ observe that
$$\int |f|^p = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n\log 2)^p \cdot\frac{1}{4^n} = (\log 2)^p \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{n^p}{4^n} <\infty .$$

Answer (score 2):

It often helps to restate the problem in terms of another, related function. Let's shift the focus from $f$ to $g=e^{|f|}$. The function $g$ has to at least $1$ everywhere, be unbounded and its integral over the set $\{g>1\}$ must be equal to $1$. The fact that $f\in L^p$ for finite $p$ will follow automatically because $e^{|f|}$ dominates $|f|^p$ for any finite $p$.

To come up with such $g$, take any unbounded integrable function $h$ on a finite interval $I$, such that $h>1$ on $I$. (I'm sure you know explicit functions of this kind). The integral $\int_I h$ will be... something. Probably not $1$. But you can *rescale* $h$ and its interval by considering $h(ax)$ with $a>0$. This contributes the factor of $a^{-1}$ to the integral,  allowing it to be adjusted to $1$.